# [Firmware Bug]: the BIOS has corrupted hw-PMU resources and CentOS 7 not initializing

Tags: linux, centos, bios, corruption, xfs

So I was on my desktop computer as usual, and then this happens out of nowhere:

[image]

For the little time that I've researched about the error, the first message `[Firmware Bug]: the BIOS has corrupted hw-PMU` seems to be related to HP hardware (I have a printer connected to my computer). The problem is that my CentOS 7 is not booting anymore. I guess that the problem might be because of the following message: `Corruption of in-memory data detected. Shutting down filesystem`. I'm also asking this question on the same desktop computer using Windows on a dual boot.

Is there a way to recover from this? I don't even know where to start looking for a fix.

**UPDATE:**

When I try to boot into CentOS, it displays me the same lines shown in the image (the ones starting with `[    2.0XXXXX] XFS (dm-1) ...` and then it enters in emergency mode. It then tells me that there's a log file at `/run/initramfs/rdsosreport.txt`. I wanted to copy that file to a USB drive so that I could share the error log, but apparently I can't mount it.

Using `dmesg` I can see that my pendrive is detected, but no name is associated to it in the `dev` directory. I've tried formatting my pendrive to `ext2` but I still have the same problem. Is there anything I'm missing here?

Any help is appreciated.

**UPDATE 2:**

It turned out that I had my root filesystem currupted by the crash, as stated in the comments. I followed shodanshok's suggestion and booted a live CentOS image on my USB stick, then I went to `Troubleshooting` and selected the option to rescue an existing installation of CentOS.

Funnily enough, the live image stated that no Linux installation were found on my hard drive, so I didn't know what to do again. I returned to Google to search for a solution and found [this blog post](https://jc-lan.tk/2016/11/13/centos-7-fails-to-boot-xfs-corruption-enters-emergency-mode/). The guy there apparently had the same problem, and he solved it using this command: `xfs_repair -L /dev/mapper/centos-root`.

I returned to my live USB boot and selected the rescue option. The live system couldn't find my Linux installation as before. That time I entered the shell and ran `fdisk -l` to see if I could manually find and mount my system partition. `fdisk` showed me the existence of a 50Gb sized `/dev/mapper/cl-root`. I wasn't able to mount it. I then ran the command `xfs_repair -L /dev/mapper/cl-root` to see what would happen. When the process ended, I rebooted my computer and CentOS is now starting without errors.

Comment: I think, there is only root filesystem corruption. Look for XFS recovery help.

Comment: I just did a little more research and that seems to be the case. I'll try running a CentOS rescue disk and see where this leads me. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Something caused a memory corruption, which was propagated to the root filesystem (to its journal, to be precise). So XFS shutdown itself down. To correct the issue, boot from a live CentOS disk and execute `xfs_repair`.

After that, you had to determine what caused the memory corruption. I see two main possibilities (other than bad luck):

- a RAM module failing, which you can hunt down by running `memtest86` for 2+ hours;
- a bad/defective SATA/power cable or a bad PSU, which caused bad metadata on the disk drive and a subsequent shutdown on metadata reads. Please report the output of `smartctl -a <disk>` to check for this problem.

Comment: Executing `xfs_repair` did solve my problem. I'll update my question with how I solved it as it might help future users.

Comment: Thanks  for a tip. I have a same problem on ext4, I'll run `fsck.ext4`.